# Setting the text to checkbox dynamically in android

Tags: android

I need to create checkboxes dynamically in android. I am getting the value in my code but unable to set that value to checkbox.

My Code:

```
CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[20]; 
for(int k=0; k<stringList3.size(); k++)
{
 System.out.println("stringlist3 in for loop"+stringList3.get(0));
 arr = stringList3.get(k);
 cbs[k] = new CheckBox(getContext());
 System.out.println("arr values"+arr.get(0));
 System.out.println("arr values"+arr.get(1));
 System.out.println("arr values"+arr.get(2));
 cbs[k].setText((CharSequence) arr.get(2));
 Rl.addView(cbs[k]);
                 }
```

Here when I am setting the value arr.get(2) to checkbox it is not setting ...please help me regarding this...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with constant string like "Check Box Testing" in place of (CharSequence) arr.get(2) confirm whether the problem with **arr** or cbs[k] try it

Comment: hi i have tried keeping like cbs[k].setText("hello");..but even then text is not setting...do we need to create a textview in layout for dynamically generated checkboxes?

Comment: is Rl relative layout in XML file?

Comment: yes Rl layout i am referring from my xml file...checkboxes are displaying but only that text is not setting to it..please help me

Comment: can you post the declarations and definitions of stringList3 and arr ?

Comment: Hi in stringlist3 arraylist it is storing values as [1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],.....so I am storing each item in arr..i.e arr contains only [1,1,1,1] at a time..now i want to set arr.get(2) value to checkbox....

Comment: Hi I have done small mistake...It is displaying the text...Since I have kept the background color white the text color is mixing with the background color...now i kept  cbs[k].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); and it is working fine.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you written remaining code, just check your code with below example.

[Dynamically adding views to layout](http://as400samplecode.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html)

I think in your code, the problem may be **stringList3.size()** returning more than **20**, so that you are getting force close. Just check it once.